# Apache POI - setting left/right print margin in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is that possible - with apache POI - to set left or right print margin for Excel sheet?

The default margins are quite big. I cannot see neither setLeftMargin nor setRightMargin in XSSFPrintSetup, but only header and footer:

```
    XSSFPrintSetup printSetup = (XSSFPrintSetup) sheet.getPrintSetup();
    printSetup.setHeaderMargin(0.5D);
    printSetup.setFooterMargin(0.5D);
```

Is there any kind friend that could help me a little?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The sheet margins are not contained in the `XSSFPrintSetup` object, but on the `XSSFSheet` itself.  Use `Sheet`'s [`getMargin`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getMargin%28short%29) and [`setMargin`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setMargin%28short,%20double%29) methods, passing the appropriate `Sheet` constant for the top/left/bottom/right/header/footer margins.  Set and get the margin in inches.

```
double leftMarginInches = sheet.getMargin(Sheet.LeftMargin);
sheet.setMargin(Sheet.RightMargin, 0.5 /* inches */ );
```

Answer (score 0):

for Kotlin the following works:

```
    // set margins to 0.5 cm = 0.197 inches
    xlWSheet.setMargin(Sheet.LeftMargin, 0.197)
    xlWSheet.setMargin(Sheet.RightMargin, 0.197)
    xlWSheet.setMargin(Sheet.TopMargin, 0.197)
    xlWSheet.setMargin(Sheet.BottomMargin, 0.197)
```

Comment: implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.1'
    // !!! the latest 5.2.3 is only for Android 8.0 (API 26) or higher
    implementation group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '3.1.0'
    // !!! the latest 5.1.1 is only for Android 8.0 (API 26) or higher

Comment: If you need to edit your answer click the [edit] button. I recommend you read [answer]

Answer (score -1):

The enumeration is now MarginType.LeftMargin, -RightMargin

```
double leftMargin = sheet.GetMargin(MarginType.LeftMargin);
double rightMargin = sheet.GetMargin(MarginType.RightMargin);
```

**Update:**

The code preceding this code is:

```
            var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(sheetname);
            double leftMargin = sheet.GetMargin(MarginType.LeftMargin);
            double rightMargin = sheet.GetMargin(MarginType.RightMargin);
```

This is indeed the NPOI.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the same software here? Only the [Apache POI method is Sheet.getMargin not Sheet.GetMargin](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getMargin%28short%29), and there's no `MarginType` enum defined in POI

Comment: Yes, I have added some more code from my working example to demonstrate the origin.

Comment: The OP has tagged their question [tag:java], so is presumably asking about Apache POI rather than NPOI. As such, it would seem that your answer is at best confusing, or at worst plain wrong :/

Comment: This post came up under a search of NPOI.  While I appreciate that it is POI, not the .NET wrapper NPOI, the approaches are similar and someone else doing the same search I did will find the same topic and perhaps the real answer they were looking for.  NPOI IS POI:   just under the .NET interface.

Comment: They are completely different codebases these days, as evidenced in this case by the lack of a `MarginType` interface in Apache POI (Java), which means your answer doesn't work!

Comment: Many of us work in multiple C/Perl/Java/PHP/C++/C#Javascript etc languages with similar style and interfaces and the similarities in conceptual approaches are more important than the details of the differences in implementation.